# Lock an randomized array so it can be processed from other methods without getting randomized

Tags: java, arrays, blackjack

I'm doing a blackjack game in java and made a method that creates a deck of cards and then a method that shuffles the deck. I need the array list of cards too other functions, for example a method that draws cards but each time I call on the method it shuffles a new deck. I want to avoid that, but I don't know how...

These methods define and shuffles the deck:

```
public static String[] kortlek() {

    String suit[] = { "S", "D", "C", "H" };
    String rank[] = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J",
            "Q", "K", "A" };
    String[] deck = new String[52];
    String[] shuffledDeck = new String[deck.length];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        deck[i] = rank[i % 13] + suit[i / 13];

    } // End of for loop

    deck = shuffledDeck(deck); 

    return deck;
}

public static String[] shuffledDeck(String [] shuffledDeck) {


    for (int i = 0; i < shuffledDeck.length; i++) {
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * shuffledDeck.length);

        String temp = shuffledDeck[i];
        shuffledDeck[i] = shuffledDeck[index];
        shuffledDeck[index] = temp;

    } // End of loop

    for (int i = 0; i < shuffledDeck.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(shuffledDeck[i]);
    }
    return shuffledDeck;
}
```

This method with a button actionListener method draws a card:

```
public static String drawCard(int wichCard) {

    String[] deck = kortlek();

    String drawnCard = deck[0 + wichCard];
    System.out.println("The drawn card is: " + drawnCard);

    return drawnCard; 
}
```

actionListener:

```
if (event.getSource() == drawCard) {            

    counter++;
    String drawnCard = cardDeck.drawCard(counter);
    player.setText("The drawn card is: " + drawnCard);  
}
```

The output will be:

```
first draw:
1  2  3  4  5
drawn card = 1

2nd draw:
5  3  2  1  4
drawn card = 3

3rd draw:
5  2  4  1  3
drawn card = 4
```

I want the list to not randomize each time I draw a card. How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move `String[] deck = new String[52];` out of the `kortlek()` function and make it a static member of the `cardDeck` class.

Comment: Or use a `List` to represent your deck, and have `return Collections.unmodifiableList(deck);` when you're returning it to other classes.

Comment: Also, maybe read up on `Enum`s in java.  They'll make things much more readable than using `String`s for `Suit` and `Rank`.

Comment: I love that the `blackjack` tag has 14 followers.

Comment: I'm unsure of what I am doing wrong right now... I moved the method to a separate class and then called on the other methods to define and shuffling the deck. 

static String[] kortlek() {
  
  String[] deck = new String[52];
  
  deck = cardDeck.cardDefiner(deck); // set values to deck
  deck = shuffledDeck(deck); // Shuffles the deck
  
  return deck;
 }

When I draw I just want to pick an element and move one to the right each time it is called.